# why do my normal maps from blender look like this when I bake them?

Tags: texturing

When I bake a normal map they come out like this and then they of course dont work with my models correctly.

To make this an easy demonstration - this is just a square with a brick texture on it. The geometry is is just a subdivided cube with no modifications.

[image]

Comment: Could you show how are you using those maps with your object? Are you baking in Object Space? Could you show your baking settings?

Comment: Yes I baked it in Blender 2.79b

Bake type - Normal
Space - Object

I used a displacement modifier connected to a high resolution .png brick texture (no transparency on the texture). Texture is very detailed 3338x3338 

thank you very much